# Stacked IFs Google Sheets Apps Script

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets

New to Google Apps Script. Could someone tell me to to write stacked IFs in Apps Script.
I want to create a custom function that calculates the total sixteenths in a custom feet-inches-sixteens format.
The format is different depending on the length of the string. 1=1', 12=12',508 = 5 1/2", 1604 = 16 1/4", etc...and in order to convert to feet-inches-sixteen I have to calculate the total 16ths first.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What research did you do till now? Do you have a code you're working on? Can you provide a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on, free of sensitive information, clearly indicating the desired outcome?

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear in my question, but the format itself is a bit confusing. Here's a link to a spreadsheet that might explain things better.  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BU9X8w_KVJ00-zTmXPxZ0qvUUEhjszZFG_YuU2jwGyc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little hard to understand, but I think you have values in sheets represented as 1' 3 1/2" (1 ft, 3.5 in) which you'd like to convert to sixteenth-inch units.

The following function should do what you want:

```
function SIXTEENTHS(string) {
  var regex = /^\s*([0-9]*(?=\'))?\'?\s*([0-9]+(?![0-9]))?\s*([0-9]+\/[0-9]+)?\"?\s*$/;
  var parsed = string.match(regex);
  if (!parsed) {
    return 'Bad input';
  }
  var inches = (parsed[1] | 0) * 12; // Parse feet
  inches += (parsed[2] | 0); // Parse inches
  if (parsed[3]) {
    inches += (parsed[3].split('/').reduce((a, b) => a/b)); // Parse fractions
  }
  return inches*16;
}
```

Parsing the string is a little tricky, but you can see what the regex is doing and test it at [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/pvBLQH/1).

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear in my question, but the format itself is a bit confusing. Here's a link to a spreadsheet that might explain things better.  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BU9X8w_KVJ00-zTmXPxZ0qvUUEhjszZFG_YuU2jwGyc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The reason I want to convert to 16ths first is so I can do calculations with my measurements like adding or multiplying.

Comment: The input format you're using leaves some ambiguity. How do I tell the difference between 5 ft 8 in and 5 8/16 in? Both would be written as 508. The function could easily be tweaked to return the desired format (or you could do this in sheets with the QUOTIENT and MOD functions). But first you need a consistent unambiguous format for the input data.

Comment: 5'8" would be written as 50800, 5-1/2" (or 5-8/16") would be 508. Like I said, the format is a bit confusing but it works. I updated the spreadsheet to clarify how the function works.

Comment: I've made in work in Excel with a couple of helper columns, but I want to get away from that.

Comment: Here is my rudimentary spreadsheet. All measurement conversions are on the Calculations page. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Gjx7c4xW2uztLB3uhw91E8TmtMRjCHB9uIZZlM9UoRo/edit?usp=sharing